# Best material selection for a component containing hot saturated-level saline water with high chloride content (Polymer vs coated metal)

Tags: polymers, metal, materials, corrosion

I have a component (Which can be seen as the attached file)

and inside the component, there would be hot saturated-level saline water with high chloride content (Not shown)

Considerations:

- The operating pressure inside the component is 5% to 10% higher than the atmospheric pressure.
- The saline water temperature would be about 100 C
- The chloride content of water is at least +230 ppt
- Sealing of the components is important
- There are some millimetric holes on the surface

Our preferences:

- Not to use expensive metals such as Titanium or Super duplex
- Polymer is preferred as the material of the component
- Cheaper metals with a non-expensive coating are also preferred
- The expansion coefficient of the material is preferred to be as low as possible to prevent distortion and shape change (such as many polymers) otherwise the sealing and maintenance would be difficult

Based on the above explanations, What do you think?

What would be the best cheapest available material with the cheapest production process? Do you recommend polymer materials (which one and why) or coated metals?

> [image]

Comment: I don't understand your comment well, You say that we should have more chloride in water for saturated-level saline water? The TDS of the water is +350,000 ppm and the chloride content is more than 80,000 ppm. Actually the relation between saturated-level saline water salt and chloride is not important what is important is material selection

Comment: Saturated saline could have, just roughly from the top of my head, some 350 g NaCl/L, what is some 350*35.5/(23+35.5)=212 g Cl-/L. That definitely is not 80 ppt as parts per trillion, like 80 ng/kg. ( Errorneously taken before as ppb, 1000 times more ) // What exactly do you mean by +80 ppt and what is its relation to saturated saline.?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, the condition at least has to be 80 g Cl-/L and could reach 212 g Cl-/L. In addition to Na+ we have Ca2+, Mg2+, SO4 2- (the condition is not steady). I have corrected and edited my question. Our concern is which material would be the cheapest and the most efficient material for our application in water with super high chloride content.

Comment: For strange reasons you insist on errorneous usage of parts per trillion.

Comment: Does it make difference using ppt, ppm or g/L, or other units? if using ppt is not professional please let me know

Comment: Using ppm, ppb, ppt is professional, but not recommended, as there must be clearly stated if you mean mass, volume or molar amount. Also, it is sometimes incorrectly used with mixed quantities. E.g. ppm as mg/L is not fully correct, as it implies 1 L has mass 1 kg.

Comment: In the olden days in the USA, ppt meant parts per thousand. Sad, but true. For decades now, ppt means parts per trillion.

Comment: One more reason why not to use ppx concept. Using ppt as part per thousand is very strongly discouraged, leading surely to confusion with part per trillion. %, promile or as the best option explicit units like g/L or g/kg are suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on size, fiberglass would likely be cheapest; one would need to research epoxy or polyester for binder. More costly would be rubber lined steel. Rubber lined steel rail cars and storage tanks have been used many decades for super phosphoric  acid  at about 300 F. I do not recall the specific rubber.

Comment: Could FRP coating also resist under such conditions? for example ST37 steel+frp coating?

Comment: Rubber is what is used; and any steel. Some coatings would likely work but they would need test history or new tests.